# Converting Date Format to numeric Date

Tags: java

I have a Date in this format:

```
Tue Mar 10 00:00:00 UTC 1987
```

It is stored in a Object Date.

```
Object tmp = solrDoc.getFieldValue("date_from")
```

I would like to convert it to a strictly numeric format, without the hours, timezone etc., like

```
10.03.1987
```

This is what I tried so far:

```
DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
date.format(tmp);
```

It returns:

```
 "java.text.SimpleDateFormat@7147a660"
```

Comment: Convert the `Object` to `Date` and then pass it to the converter.

Comment: You need `String formattedDate = date.format(tmp);`.

Comment: If you have date in such format, then `dd.MM.yyyy` will not work at all.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon this solved my problem.. I kinda always struggle with date datatypes..

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Please search before asking. Formatting of dates has been covered literally hundreds of times already. So you’ll find a good answer much faster that way.

Answer (score 2):

You're attempting to use the `format` method on an `Object`, but according to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format(java.util.Date)), you need to pass this method a `Date`. So what you actually need to do is parse that original `String` into a `Date`, then format that.

For example, you could do it like this:

```
String tempString = String.valueOf(solrDoc.getFieldValue("date_from"));
DateFormat formatToRead = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
DateFormat formatToWrite = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
formatToWrite.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date tempDate = null;
String result = null;
try {
    tempDate = formatToRead.parse(tempString);
} catch(ParseException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
if(tempDate != null){
    result = formatToWrite.format(tempDate);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Note that I had to set the `TimeZone` on the `formateToWrite` in order to keep it in UTC.

If you want more information on the `SimpleDateFormat` that I used to parse your original `String`, please refer to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4216767/8972283).

Comment: I was close, the thing I didn't do is to store the formated value in a String object.. after I did that, it worked just fine.. Thank you for your answere